# Color palete like pixelate photo in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm like the one here http://www.cssdrive.com/imagepalette/index.php "Complete Color Pallete" which finds the color pallete of a given photo.

Answer (score 2):

You can read each pixel color value using [imagecolorat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) and some loops and count the frequency of each color.  You may also want to round close colors together for this step so that you don't just have a flat histogram.  Once you have a histogram of each color made go through and find the n highest points and these are the n colors you should use.  Good luck.

```
function findPallete($filename, $palletesize) {
   $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
   $dimensions = getimagesize($filename);
   $frequencies = array();
   for($x=0;$x<$dimensions[0];$x++) 
      for($y=0;$y<$dimensions[1];$y++) 
          $frequencies[imagecolorat($im,$x,$y)]++;
   array_multisort($frequencies,SORT_DESC);
   return array_keys(array_slice($frequencies,0,$palletesize));
}
```